# Build USPS web service request

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, url

I want to build a web service request which accesses USPS's address web service.
I am facing a problem with building the request URL string in the format they want.
What i want to do is give the zip code in a variable so that it can be dynamic.
But USPS web service isn't accepting the URL string I am sending, guess I am making a mistake with the format.

The format which USPS expects is:

```
<CityStateLookupRequest USERID=”xxxxxxxx”>
<ZipCode ID="0">
<Zip5>90210</Zip5>
</ZipCode>
<ZipCode ID="1">
<Zip5>20770</Zip5>
</ZipCode>
</CityStateLookupRequest> 

https://servername/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRe
quest USERID="username">.......</CityStateLookupRequest>
```

This is how I am trying to build the URL:

```
WebRequest USPSReq = String.Format("http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=CityStateLookupRequest&USERID=xxxxxxxx&ZipCode ID=0&Zip5=" + oZip);
```

How can I build this request URL?

Comment: Are they expecting a GET, or a POST? In particular, are you sure they want that XML to be in the query string? If they do, then the problem is, that's not XML

Comment: Ok, the reference is [Address Information APIs](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information.htm), and they really _do_ want the XML in the URL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply build that XML using your favorite XML API. For instance:

```
XDocument requestXml = new XDocument(
    new XElement("CityStateLookupRequest",
        new XAttribute("USERID", userID),
        new XElement("ZipCode",
            new XAttribute("ID", "0"),
            new XElement("ZIP5", zip5)));
var requestUrl = new UriBuilder("http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll");
requestUrl.Query = "API=CityStateLookup&XML=" + requestXml.ToString();
var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl.Uri);
```